# missing template of xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a mobile app using xamarin according to [this](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter1/firstapp_pc/) tutorial. I'm working on a windows 10 PC with VS2017 community.
when I got to the part of creating a new cross-platform project, I get to the following window in my PC:
[image]

as you can see, the marked app is "Cross Platform App (Xamarin)". this is different than what shown in the tutorial - there it's "Cross Platform App (**Xamarin.Forms or Native**)". It seemed negligible at first, but as I proceeded with the tutorial I found out that I am missing some of the components mentioned there, so I do believe there's a problem.
Any idea how to get that missing template?

Comment: When you select the option on screenshot you can select if it Forms or Native - the same as shown in tutorial. What are other components you are missing?

Comment: @YuriS under "Building the Common Library" - it says that there's a folder called "Abstractions" but I can't see it. I thought that I misunderstood so I searched in the entire solution some words that are in the code snippets at that part - such as "ICloudTable", "TableData" etc. - and I didn't find any of those in the solution...

Comment: That is not related directly to the project itslef. Did you do that - "You should also install the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client library in all the client projects." Seems you are missing some nugets

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure I did that...

Comment: then pick another blog :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that tutorial he uses Visual Studio 2017 (v15.1) this is an old version. You have installed Visual Studio 2017 (v15.3) this is the most recent version.

But do not worry, just changed the name of the template. After clicking on the option you will get something like this:

[image]

You can see the release notes here:

[Visual Studio 2017 (v15.1)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.1)

[Visual Studio 2017 (v15.3)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes)

Comment: that seems to be the issue, I'll accept that :) thanks